# Android - How to animate a single element of Canvas instead of whole canvas or view?

Tags: android, canvas, jquery-animate, paint, alpha

I have a custom view with two lines that had been drawn using drawLine function. I want to animate the alpha of second line but whenever i try to animate it whole canvas is animating. I try to find like anything so far but didn't get any luck.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do like this:

1. Implement onDraw() in your custom View
2. Do not create any object in onDraw()
3. Provide public set and get methods for your alpha field that you use in onDraw()
4. Use [ObjectAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) to animate alpha property of your custom view

Probably use also [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) instead calling invalidate() to redraw only part of your canvas.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir for your reply. But as far as i can see ObjectAnimator required a View object to animate but i have two lines which have been drawn using drawLine and i want only second line to be animated which i guess i can't pass as an object to ObjectAnimator. Would you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: Well, I've explained already. You need to create property (set and get methods for some private value). The private value would represent alpha/transparency of your second line. Once set method has been called you call invalidate. Next step is use animator on your activity and the property (transparency of second line) you just defined (set and get methods)